# How do I get data from stdin using os.system()

Tags: python, shell, curl, urllib, os.system

The only reliable method that I a have found for using a script to download text from wikipedia is with cURL. So far the only way I have for doing that is to call `os.system()`. Even though the output appears properly in the python shell I can't seem to the function it to return anything other than the exit code(`0`). Alternately somebody could show be how to properly use `urllib`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Dive into Python:](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/extracting_data.html)

```
import urllib
sock = urllib.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)")
htmlsource = sock.read()
sock.close()
print htmlsource
```

That will print out the source code for the Python Wikipedia article.  I suggest you take a look at Dive into Python for more details.

Example using urllib2 from the [Python Library Reference:](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/urllib2-examples.html)

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print f.read(100)
```

Edit: Also you might want to take a look at [wget.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Using_Wget)
Edit2: Added urllib2 example based on S.Lott's advice

Comment: Thank you, the built in help browser is almost never understandable.

Comment: urllib2 does almost the same thing, plus it handles things like  redirects more gracefully.

Comment: @S.Lott I agree.  I was just looking for a resource that GameFreak could learn more from, not just copy code from, and it turned out that the first resource I thought of, Dive into Python, used urllib.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question,
Python has a subprocess module which allows you to interact with spawned processes.http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

It allows you to read the stdout for the invoked process, and even send items to the stdin.

however as you said urllib is a much better option. if you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=urllib) stackoverflow i am sure you will find at least 10 other related questions...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternetive to urllib, you could use the libCurl [Python bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/).